# Using django 1.8 duration field to annotate a set of django objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am reading the documentation for django duration field and I cannot figure out how I can use this to annotate a set of django objects with the duration. The docs say that the db stores durations as integer and to aggregate it needs to be converted to timedelta like so:

```
timedelta(microseconds=list.aggregate(sum=Sum('duration'))['sum'])
```

My problem is that I am not sure how to use this expression as an annotation for a set of django objects. The [documentation can be found here](http://django-durationfield.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#example)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't, you can annotate the queryset with microsecond int values but you will have to iterate over the queryset and apply the above conversion to get timedelta objects

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I guess I am not understanding the code that I posted up there. Can you give me an example. I can't find a method aggregate in list.

Comment: Nevermind. My apologies. I understand now, the aggregate is a method of queryset, not a method of list. Since the word list was color-coded on their website, I thought they were referring to an actual method of list, not that I had to replace list with my queryset object. Thanks for your help. Also, there is no conversion necessary. django is smart enough to display timedeltas correctly as duration.

Comment: to clarify: if you want durations then no conversion is necessary because durations are what is stored and returned. you only need to convert if you want to get timedeltas from your annotated durations

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your comments were the answer to my question. Not sure how to accept comments as answers though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure how to use this expression as an annotation for a set of django objects

The short answer is: you can't.

If you're talking about annotating a queryset with sums, then I assume the `duration` field is on a related model (via many-to-many or reverse foreign key relation) and you want to get the sums of durations for each row of the parent model.

You can annotate the queryset with int duration values in microseconds like so:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.annotate(sum=Sum('related_model__duration'))
```

Alternatively you might have the `duration` field on `MyModel` directly but are aggregating (i.e. an SQL `GROUP BY` query):

```
qs = MyModel.objects.values('grouped_field').annotate(sum=Sum('duration'))
```

Either way, to convert these to timedeltas you could iterate over the queryset and modify the instances:

```
for obj in qs:
    obj._timedelta = timedelta(microseconds=obj.sum)
```

Looking at this code it occurs to me I'd prefer to make this a property on the model, eg:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # ...

    @property
    def timedelta(self):
        try:
            return timedelta(microseconds=self.sum)
        except AttributeError:
            # instance was not annotated (from a regular queryset)
            return None
```

Then you don't need to do the extra loop over the queryset.